# Is it possible to let nginx run as a different user for a location?

Tags: nginx, user-accounts

My nginx is running as user nobody:nogroup.

But I want a certain location of  server clause to be protected and owned by specific users. Basic Authentication is easy enough to set up, but the permission of the actual directory is not world-readable so unavailable for nginx and I get a 403 Forbidden error.

Can I tell nginx that a certain 'location' is to be accessed as a certain user?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to change the user during run-time.

When nginx starts, it does initialisation work as root user, and after that it drops privileges to become a non-privileged user.

After that point, it is not possible to change user anymore.

I suggest that you assign nginx group to the directory. For example, if nginx is a member of `www-data` group, then use the following commands:

```
chgrp www-data /path/to/directory
chmod -R g+r /path/to/directory
```